# Can I Store The String Values From MulitiColumn listView to Simple ListView in the Next Activity?

Tags: android, android-listview

**How to Get the Value from Custom ListView with two columns to Simple ListView in Next Activity.i have select1 and select2 String[] variables.Myval is Global Variable.i have the following Exceptions ***

Exceptions in the logcat:

```
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974): java.lang.NullPointerException
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at                android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
     07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2033)
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1772)
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:732)
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1625)
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1863)
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
     07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1489)
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    07-31 10:37:55.470: E/AndroidRuntime(974):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

get the value from Spinner:

```
     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos,long id) {              


  String Text = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
    if(Text.equals("----SELECT----")) {

    }       
    else if(Text.equals("BEVERAGES")){
        select1=new String[Beverage.length];
        select2=new String[P1.length];
        System.out.println("Length of Beverage:" + select1.length);
        System.out.println("Length of P1:" + select2.length);
        select1 = Beverage;
        select2 = P1;
       l1.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(HomeActivity.this));
       return;

   }
```

get the value from Custom ListView:

```
                  l1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 

                   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
                   int position, long id) { 

                   // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text 
                   Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "SELECTED :: " + "item "+select1[position] + " " + "price"+ select2[position], 
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
           String ss=(String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
           GlobalClass.myval.add(ss);
```

Comment: You can Also pass the Values through putExtra using intents.And get that Values using Bundles.

Comment: You can create adapter and set it to the simple ListView in the second activity.

Answer (score 0):

replace the following things in your code ,it may provide you with some 


**l1.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(HomeActivity.this));
      replace with :
                           l1.setAdapter(new EfficientAdapter(HomeActivity.this),arraytosendtoadapter);**

*//change your efficient adapter to have an String[] so to recieve what you send*